# MongoDB: doing an atomic create and return operation

Tags: mongodb

I need to create a document in mongodb and then immediately want it available in my application. The normal way to do this would be (in Python code):

```
doc_id = collection.insert({'name':'mike', 'email':'mike@gmail.com'})
doc = collection.find_one({'_id':doc_id})
```

There's two problems with this:

- two requests to the server
- not atomic

So, I tried using the `find_and_modify` operation to effectively do a "create and return" with the help of `upserts` like this:

```
doc = collection.find_and_modify(
    # so that no doc can be found
    query= { '__no_field__':'__no_value__'},

    # If the <update> argument contains only field and value pairs,
    # and no $set or $unset, the method REPLACES the existing document
    # with the document in the <update> argument,
    # except for the _id field
    document= {'name':'mike', 'email':'mike@gmail.com'},

    # since the document does not exist, this will create it
    upsert= True,

    #this will return the updated (in our case, newly created) document
    new= True
)
```

This indeed works as expected. My question is: whether this is the right way to accomplish a "create and return" or is there any gotcha that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you missing from a plain old regular insert call?

If it is not knowing what the _id will be, you could just create the _id yourself first and insert the document. Then you know exactly how it will look like. None of the other fields will be different from what you sent to the database.

If you are worried about guarantees that the insert will have succeeded you can check the return code, and also set a [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#write-concern) that provides enough assurances (such as that it has been flushed to disk or replicated to enough nodes).

Comment: If I don't pass the _id, is it created by the mongo client or on the server? Because if the client creates the _id, then I am probably not getting anything out of `find_and_modify`,. I thought I was server that created the missing _id

Comment: I think the client-side driver creates the _id (at least in Java), but does it make any difference who does it?

Comment: Probably not. I was just a little wary of trusting my own inserted document as exactly the same that would be returned by database and felt a little more comfortable getting a pristine copy from the database. But I guess you're right.

Comment: Just make sure you use your driver's official ObjectId class. That should work fine.